# Vertically centring a div containing two text areas

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm really struggling to vertically centre my div, which is currently serving as a container for two text areas. I have two text areas within my div, positioned side by side how I want it, and I would like them to retain their relative position to eachother, but, be vertically in the very middle of the screen. How can I do this?

App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    character: null
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Centre">
        <div className="Left">
          <TextBox
          />
        </div>
        <div className="Right">
          <textarea
            className="Box"
            placeholder={"English translation"}
            value={this.state.english}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

App.css

```
.Box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 98%;
  padding: 1%;
  border: solid 1px orange;
}

.Centre {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.Left {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  border: red;
}

.Right {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  float: Right;
  border: red;
}
```

textbox.jsx

```
class TextBox extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <textarea
          className="Box"
          placeholder="Type in Spanish"
          value={this.props.equation}
          type="text"
          name="equation"
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand, do you want 2 text area side by side?

Comment: You can try this: http://jsfiddle.net/3nyx7L8k/

Comment: @Franseco M. Yes, but I want them to be in the middle of the screen, not at the very top

Comment: @Perplexityy http://jsfiddle.net/fmerco/dao6es5h/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your css code

```
.Box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 98%;
  padding: 1%;
  border: solid 1px orange;

}

.Centre {
  height:100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.Left {
  width: 300px;
  border: red;
}

.Right {
  width: 300px;
  border: red;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/demo-jncgl)

Answer (score 0):

If i got your question right, you can use flex and center them in the middle of the div:

```
.Centre {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flexbox` with `align-items` on parent class `Centre`:

`display: flex;
align-items: center.`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="textarea-wrapper">
     <textarea>text 1</textarea> 
     <textarea>text 2</textarea> 
  </div>
</div>

#container {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

.textarea-wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
```